# Android whatsapp like call notification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Am developing a voip application. There is a background service which shows incoming call notifications, which works as expected (showing an incoming call dialog) when the phone is not locked and app is in background state.

How can i generate a dialog with interactive buttons, like whatsapp incoming call notification; even when the phone is locked?

Any heads up on this one or documentation that i can look up?

I can send an inapp notification for an incoming call, but that seems to be not enough for the purpose. I would need a full blow dialog interface which has a button or similar that would in turn open the application.

I am using Quickblox as the voip service provider.

Thanks in advance

I have tried unlocking the phone, on a button press

Here is my code to open a dialog from the background service.

```
viewToShowOnLockedScreen = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_background_call, null);
        viewToShowOnLockedScreen.setTag(TAG);

        int top = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2;

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Utils.dpToPx(300), 0, 0,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON ,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
viewToShowOnLockedScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.abc_slide_in_top);
        viewToShowOnLockedScreen.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        mWindowManager.addView(viewToShowOnLockedScreen, mLayoutParams);
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(viewToShowOnLockedScreen, mLayoutParams);
```

And here is the code to unlock the device on a button press. Though this looks like it unlocks the phone, the screen is on, but the phone is still locked. Home button does'nt work.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
        kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: u got solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, a work around i should say.

I coul'dnt unlock the screen. However I have updated the application to listen to Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT and added necessary to logic in the app to answer calls once the user has unlocked the device at the point of incoming call. Here is the code.

```
mUnlockStatusFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mUnlockStatusFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    mUnlockStateIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
                    if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                       //Do something phone is unlocked
                        Log.d(TAG,"Screen unlocked");
                        if(isWaitingForUnlock){
                            stopCallNotification();
                            if(Foreground.get().isForeground()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "App is in foreground; Sending a broadcast");
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                                intent.setAction(BaseActivityWithSignalling.onReceiveNewSession);
                                intent.putExtra("code", BaseActivityWithSignalling.onReceiveNewSessionCode);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Send broadcast for onReceiveNewSession");
                            }else{
                                Log.d(TAG, "App is in background; Showing activity");
                                Intent showCallingFromBG = new Intent(LMService.this, BackgroundCall.class);
                                showCallingFromBG.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(showCallingFromBG);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    registerReceiver(mUnlockStateIntentReceiver, mUnlockStatusFilter);
```